# asp.net core iis arr file uopload error 502.3

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, arr

I'm trying to upload large file to an asp.net core app behind arr as load balancer.

I have several iis node and a load balancer which is iis arr.

After digging throught iis log file using failed request tracing I got following error by FREB at arr level when trying to upload large file

> 502.3
>
> REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE

but if i try to upload file at the node level the file will be uploaded successfully and without any error.

i have set high request filter file size but i still get the above error

what can i do?